# How to stop customers changing password

Tags: magento2.3

> How to stop customers changing password

I curently have a b2b site where I set the same password for each store. I'd like to disable "Change Password" on the account page so no one can change the password.

> Magento 2.3.2 CE
>
> Cheers.

[image]

Comment: Overwrite the template in customer_account_index.xml layout file:
`<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Info" name="customer_account_dashboard_info" as="info" template="My_OverridingModule::account/dashboard/info.phtml" cacheable="false"/></referenceContainer>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/[theme_vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Customer/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml

And remove the code

```
<a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getChangePasswordUrl()) ?>" class="action change-password">
   <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change Password')) ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

That did the trick, cheers Kishor greatly appreaited.

Comment: Upvote the answer if it helps you.